# Bolding with ** isn't working properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068191/xcode-whats-up-with-the-nib-xib/1071737#1071737)

One of the bolds works, and the other one just turns up as ** in the actual post.

This is the string that isn't working: `**x**ml n**ib**`

Which renders as: **x**ml n**ib**

Comment: for clarity, could you put the original string, escaped in backquotes, then show us how it is rendered?  I.e.: change the last line of this post to:  The string "`**x**ml n**ib**`" gets rendered like this: **x**ml n**ib**

Comment: We've been collecting markdown bugs in another thread, so I added this one http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view/1670#1670

Comment: @Kyle I'm a bit confused as to the status of this... it's marked as "completed" but it's still broken in the same way as before, and the thread you linked is also marked as "completed". Was this actually a "wontfix"?

Comment: @romkyns: It's referring to the part of the preview not matching the actual output, as identified by the middle two sentences of this question (pre-revision).

Answer (score 9):

This is not a bug; this is by design.

It becomes very difficult to talk about code when your_variable_names_are_suddenly_underlined. Intra-word emphasis is a bad idea and we have **EXPLICITLY** disabled it.

See: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/three-markdown-gotcha/.

> **1) Markdown’s single biggest flaw is its intra-word emphasis.**
>
> I don’t think anybody writes:
>
> `un*fricking*believable`
>
> often enough to justify making it nearly impossible to talk about tokens with underscores in them:
>
> `some_file_name`
>
> is interpreted as:
>
> `some<em>file</em>name`
>
> It even works across word boundaries:
>
> `file_one and file_two`
>
> becomes:
>
> `file<em>one and file</em> two`
>
> Whenever you’re writing tokens with underscores you have to make absolutely sure you’re in a backtick-delimited code span. The same problem will also nail you on equations like a*b*c, but that seems to pop up less frequently.
>
> Showdown follows the reference implementation on all this, but in WMD I do a little preprocessing to hack the idiocy away: basically I just backslash-escape any underscores or asterisks that might trigger it. It’s a flagrant violation of the standard, but since it’s a pre-pass that should produce identical output with any Markdown processor, I feel justified. Unfortunately my hack did screw up one edge case (which I don’t have in front of me) and there isn’t any way to disable it. Both those things will change in the next release.

Comment: i guess this is for users who don't know to put backquotes around inline code?

Comment: Jeff: the problem that many of us have here isn't that the ** characters don't bold the text. It's that the behavior shown by the preview is different from the behavior shown after you post. That is what needs fixed.

Comment: So why does it work in the javascript preview then?

Comment: If I click the bold button in the editor, then I expect it to bold my text. If markdown can't do it, and html bold tags can, then the editor should be inserting bold tags.

Comment: @Tom, if you feel strongly about it, you can submit patches to the repository: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view/1688#1688

Comment: Jeff, you seem to have taken the Microsoft-patented "let's hold the poor little idiots' hands" approach to software design.  That's rather disappointing.  Intraword emphasis is legitimately useful (made-up example: the word is em**ph**asis, not em**f**asis), whereas underscore-joined names without backticks are **not** useful.  When a user mistakenly types `PLAIN_TEXT` and sees PLAIN<i>TEXT</i> instead, it's easy to correct (it's a wiki.  Just fix it), but when they type intra**word** emphasis and don't get it, it's not as easy to fix (`<b>` doesn't immediately come to mind).

Comment: This "answer" *maybe* justifies disallowing intra-word underscore-emphasis. Maybe. (And only on the techie SE sites.) It in no way, shape, or form justifies disallowing intra-word emphasis via an asterisk. (Does any programming language even allow using asterisks in variable names?)

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround, you could use "`**x**ml n<b>ib</b>`": **x**ml n**ib**

Answer (score 3):

This used to be intentional for a long time, but now it works. See [Markdown change: Intra-word emphasis now works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works).

Answer (score 1):

xml n **ib**
xml n**ib**
xml **nib**

Looks like it doesn't work when bolding partial words, which at times could be useful if you ever need to use ** inside another word sentence.

Unclear which would be better in this case, stats on how often ** is used? :p

a**b**c
ab**c**
**abc**

Comment: Gosh I wish I were better at pointers now.

Comment: you can use `<b></b>`

Answer (score 1):

A failing in the markdown parser.  It starts a bold if the bold tag starts on a word boundary, but not inside a word.

**X**ml n**IB**

But it works in the preview box correctly, so the javascript parser is correct, the server side one is not.

Answer (score 0):

It works good; just put some spaces.

> **x** ml n **ib**
>   `**x** ml n **ib**`

If you want to use it without spaces you could use `<b></b>`.

> **x**ml n**ib**
>   `<b>x</b>ml n<b>ib</b>`

You can also put `<o>` before the initial `**` and after the final `**`.

> a**aa**a = **x**ml n**ib**
>   `a<o>**aa**<o>a = **x**<o>ml n<o>**ib**`

Answer (score 0):

Is a double asterisk a left bracket, or a right bracket, or a single asterisk that's been escaped?
It gets worse.  A single asterisk can be a left bracket or a right bracket as well.  If I remember right, single asterisk indicates italics.  No matter how you write the parser, there are going to be complaints.

*This text was bracketed by single asterisks.*

To see the problem more clearly, consider quoted text inside of CSV.  A quote mark can be a left bracket or a right bracket.  A double quote is typically an escaped single quote.  Quotes cannot be nested.