# URL shows differently on copy-paste

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks, url-encoding

I tried to copy-paste the following google search url in comments:

```
 http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=lang:c+%22char+***%22&sbtn=Search
```

But it shows like this

> http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=lang:c+%22char+***%22&sbtn=Search

Maybe this is due to markdown syntax (** **). But, it should be taken care of, right?

Comment: I guess meta is sleeping right now :D

Comment: There's always someone lurking...

Comment: Actually that's a lie, I'm not lurking, I'm avoiding a problem customer

Comment: It's interpreted as intra-word emphasis http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/bug-bolding-with-isnt-working-properly/1669#1669 - Try to escape the asterisks.

Comment: @John Smithers: okay,thanks. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To steal John Smither's answer-as-a-comment: you'll want to escape the asterisks in the URL, or use a URL shortening service.

We usually discourage URL shorteners, but you have enough weird characters in this one that it's probably OK.

**Edit:** Also note that this works fine if you use the link button (or Ctrl-L) to insert the link.

Comment: jeff atwood stealing! :D