# Why markdown **bold** rendered as italic on parts of words?

Tags: bug, design, markdown-rendering

When I try to `**bo**ld` part of the word it turns out weird.

It's rendered as: 
 **bo**ld as you can see the *BO* is italic.

I rarely use it but lets say I want to emphasis _un_downvote what should I do?

You can see it *should* work here [Bolding with ** isn't working properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/bug-bolding-with-isnt-working-properly) the word **x**ml

**x**ml n**ib**
[image]

Comment: Nope, it doesn't and that is how it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's *intentional*, not a bug.  Otherwise writing something such as "this_is_my_file_name.txt" would come out looking really weird.

Proper markdown actually does behave as you're describing, but Jeff decided <sup>1</sup> to divert from those specs in this one case as that pattern was so commonly used on this site; he didn't want users to need to escape such file names whenever they were used.

If you want to bold **pa**rt of a word then use HTML, not markup (`<b>exam</b>ple`).

<sup>1</sup> [Source](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/12/responsible-open-source-code-parenting.html)

Comment: I edited my question with a working example

Comment: @raam86 And my answer has had a working example from when it was first posted...

Comment: I did see and it is amazing but if you look at the link you will notice it's working with **X**ML

Comment: @raam86 Presumably the rendering engine was slightly different 4 years ago and the rendered content is cached.  Editing the question (thus forcing it to re-render) results in what I would expect, which seems prove that to be the explanation.

Comment: why not enable intra-word highlighting for asterisks but not underscores?

Comment: @JanDvorak You're more than welcome to propose that as a feature request if you would like (assuming you don't find any duplicates first).

Comment: @servy still bold after edit please see post.

Comment: @raam86 I edited the question, not the answer.  (I intentionally left the answer so you could see both.)  If it bothers you *that* much I can edit the answer as well.

Comment: @servy Am I the only one seeing tehe **question** as <b>x*</b>ml

Comment: @raam86 I see what you see in your screenshot.  What you see in the question is intentional; what you see in the answer is, as I said, no longer how the markup will be rendered, and the only reason it appears that way is because the rendered content has been cached for a long time.  You can't use that markup to post intra-word bolding anymore.