# Make the bold and italic buttons context sensitive for intra-word emphasis

Tags: feature-request, markdown

**Background**
When using bold for whole words the bold button works excellently:

> `**bold**` becomes **bold** and `*italic*` becomes *italic*.

However when trying to apply formatting to just one letter it doesn't work

> `**b**old` becomes **b**old and `*i*talic` becomes *i*talic.

This is for **very good reasons** which have been explored in depth every time this feature request/(not a) bug is discussed: [Bolding with ** isn't working properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/bolding-with-isnt-working-properly), [Why markdown **bold** rendered as italic on parts of words?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188249/why-markdown-bold-rendered-as-italic-on-parts-of-words?lq=1) etc etc etc and is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). However in each case the easy work around is also discussed:

> `<b>b</b>old` becomes **b**old and `<i>i</i>talic` becomes *i*talic.

**Feature Request**
Therefore; i'd like to propose the feature request that the bold and italic buttons detect the context they're in and use the `**bold**` or `<b>b</b>old` formatting as appropriate.

The code button already does this context detection: it detects whether it is inline code in which case it formats it as `'code'` or if its block code it indents it; which leads to a very good user experience. Something similar on the bold and italic buttons would probably avoid many meta questions about (not) bugs and feature requests