# Markdown in an old closing reason is not rendered correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, markdown, close-reasons

On [Bolding with ** isn't working properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/bug-bolding-with-isnt-working-properly), the closing reason contains Markdown markup that is rendered as it were plain text.

[image: screenshot]

`[network](https://stackexchange.com/sites)` should be rendered as [network](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: That was closed way back in '09. It's probably a remnant of an era long gone bye. Namely, when Jeff closed stuff. Let's keep the typo for posterity. : )

Comment: @Undo Actually, it looks like markdown broke in close reasons. I've seen this several times today, intermittently. I also don't think it's limited to _old_ close reasons, specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in release 2013.7.11.838. Since the linked question in the bug report has been reopened, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100083) is another that can be used to verify it's working as expected. (The link is only for 10K users and moderators.)

[image: screenshot]