# Anchor tags not processed in close vote review queue close reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, meta

This is a minor bug. One anchor tag is visible, other(?) has been processed correctly.

[image]

Comment: looking at it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues is connected to this one: [Markdown in an old closing reason is not rendered correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188329/markdown-in-an-old-closing-reason-is-not-rendered-correctly/188369#188369)

Will be fixed in next release.

Comment: So, close reasons in the queue having *both* HTML and markdown will be rendered properly now?

Comment: everything will be rendered correctly with markdown; the html was displayed just because I edited a site setting property (which was previously in markdown), trying to fix the issue linked in the answer